# Is there an exoplanet API or dataset?

Tags: data-request, api, astronomy

I am looking for an API or dataset that has information about the known [exoplanets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exo_planet). The properties of this dataset would include things like mass, orbital period, atmosphere, temperature, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a little searching, I found what I was looking for. NASA has an archive of Exoplanets, as well as an API for it. The data are updated weekly.

- [Archive Home](http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/index.html)
- [API](http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/program_interfaces.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether it's duplicative but [here's another link](http://exoapi.com/).

*(Disclaimer - I am the Sr. API Strategist for GSA)*

Answer (score 3):

The NASA Exoplanet archive also has a [bulk download feature](http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/bulk_data_download/).

Answer (score 2):

More generically, the astronomical community has a number of standardized APIs managed by the [International Virtual Observatory Alliance (IVOA)](http://www.ivoa.net/):

- http://www.ivoa.net/documents/

Some things that people might consider 'astronomical' the science community calls 'planetary', and their primary system in the United States is the [Planetary Data System](http://pds.nasa.gov/), and their standards are the basis for the [International Planetary Data Alliance (IPDA)](http://planetarydata.org/) :

- http://planetarydata.org/

... of course, you then have to find the appropriate endpoint to talk to.